# Find the value of the following expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across the following problem in an Exam that says:
Find the value of  the expression  $$\left(\frac{1}{x^{a-b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-c}}\times\left(\frac{1}{x^{b-c}}\right)^{\frac{1}{b-a}}\times\left(\frac{1}{x^{c-a}}\right)^{\frac{1}{c-b}}=?$$

This problem contains only $1$ mark and I do not know how to solve it in the shortest possible way.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

**EDIT:** Sorry, for the mistake on my part. It will be multiplicative sign instead by "+" sign in between the terms. Also , Here the expressions are $x$ to the power...I could not LATEX it properly.

[image]

Comment: have you tried to make a common denumerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multiple choice situation one might simply note that "obviously" the expression will be $x^A$ for some $A$ depending on $a,b,c$ after simplification.
As the only suggested answers are constant numbers, the expression $x^A$ in fact must not depend on $a,b,c,x$. Especially, $A$ must be a constant and then $x^A$ must be constant. The only power of $x$ that does not depend on $x$ is $x^0=1$. Thus *if* any of the given answers is correct, then it *must* be (3) $1$.

Comment: I like the argument, and of course I agree, but somehow it isn't as satisfying as actually giving a calculation for this kind of problem.

Comment: Might be better to simply say let $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(\frac{1}{x^{a-b}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-c}}\times\left(\frac{1}{x^{b-c}}\right)^{\frac{1}{b-a}}\times\left(\frac{1}{x^{c-a}}\right)^{\frac{1}{c-b}}
=x^{-\left(\frac{a-b}{a-c}+\frac{b-c}{b-a}+\frac{c-a}{c-b}\right)}
$$
I don't see a way to simplify further without any other constraints.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in the original statement, because the exponent becomes $-\frac{3}{2}$ when $a=0,$ $b=1,$ and $c=2$ (hence, none of the options can be correct). For what it's worth, there is an old algebraic technique that involves putting things in [cyclic order](https://www.google.com/search?q=fractions+%22cyclic+order%22+algebra&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) that might be useful here, once the problem is correctly stated.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{x(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac1{x(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac1{x(c-a)(c-b)}$$

$$=-\frac1{x(a-b)(c-a)}-\frac1{x(b-c)(a-b)}-\frac1{x(c-a)(b-c)}$$

$$=-\frac{b-c+c-a+a-b}{x(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

For each of your fractions, notice that $$\left(\frac{1}{x^{(a-b)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-c}}=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{a-b}{a-c}}.$$ Doing this for each fraction, we end up with $$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{a-b}{a-c}+\frac{b-c}{b-a}+\frac{c-a}{c-b}}.$$Now all we need to do is calculate what the exponent comes out to be: $$\frac{a-b}{a-c}+\frac{b-c}{b-a}+\frac{c-a}{c-b}=\frac{a-b}{a-c}+1.$$ The simplification was done by using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5b%28a-b%29%28b-a%29%28c-b%29%2B%28b-c%29%28a-c%29%28c-b%29%2B%28c-a%29%28a-c%29%28c-b%29%5d%2F%5b%28a-b%29%28a-c%29%28b-c%29%5d). If you follow the link and trust Wolfram at the moment, then we can use the last two equalities given to in fact deduce that we have the expression equal to $1$, as we knew should be the case.

Comment: Why would $\frac{b-c}{b-a}+\frac{c-a}{c-b}=1$?

Comment: @robjohn: Maybe a mistake on Wolfram's part? I provided a link in case just such an issue came up.

Comment: The last "c-b" in your equation is supposed to be a "b-a".

Comment: This looks like the proper [W|A link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+[%28a-b%29%28b-a%29%28c-b%29%2B%28b-c%29%28a-c%29%28c-b%29%2B%28a-b%29%28a-c%29%28b-a%29]%2F[%28a-c%29%28b-a%29%28c-b%29]).